# Basic Authentication in Squid Server(behind NAT) over internet

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-14.04, basic-authentication, squid

I have googled for "basic authentication not working over internet in squid server" kind of searches with no appropriate answer for my problem.

Here is my problem: 
I have set up a squid proxy server behind a firewall. I have forwarded a port (54321) to port 9999 where squid proxy is listening. Now everything is fine. I can connect to this proxy from anywhere. But I needed some kind of authentication, thus enabled basic_ncsa_auth. Now, I can access internet after authentication from my LAN computers. Fine, everything is going as I wanted to but,

from internet I have popup for username/password (firefox), and after authentication I get "cache access denied" message from squid proxy.

I would really appreciate if someone points me what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my squid.conf file:

```
http_port 9999
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid3/passwd
auth_param basic realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
```

Network setup:
Firewall static IP: Port: 54321 forwarded to Proxy server: 10.11.12.8:9999.

Answer (score 2):

Does your Squid configuration permit http_reply_access?

```
http_reply_access allow all
```

If your passwords are longer than 8 characters, you also need to make sure you are not using DES hashing, which is the default for the htpasswd command.

Here's how to create a new password file using the MD5 hashing algorithm:

```
[root@localhost ~] htpasswd -cm /tmp/passwd testuser
New password: 
Re-type new password: 
Adding password for user testuser
```

Check the contents of the file:

```
[root@localhost ~] cat /tmp/password
testuser:$apr1$VxCDyltg$krZ6v7VrnULVOiuS0u6KD1
```

Verify password using basic_ncsa_auth:

```
[root@localhost ~] /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /tmp/passwd
testuser superspurs
OK
```

Now verify at the CLI:

```
[root@TLABprx00 ~]# http_proxy=http://localhost:9999/ curl http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt --proxy-user testuser:superspurs
Microsoft NCSI
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. As I said everything is working fine, except authentication from internet to the proxy gives me "access denied error", and after sometime I found that Chromium/Chrome can authenticate successfully and working as expected but Firefox cannot... it shows "cache access denied" message. I am using chrome right now just because Firefox isn't authenticating to proxy server. (Firefox shows authentication box and after entering credentials it displays the access denied error. WEIRD.)